# codeigiter php how to display count of variable with condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how can i display total request based on approve status.
this my view to display the count of request based on approve status

```
 <?php
  foreach($requests as $request):
       $sum_item= count($request->is_approved == 2);

endforeach;
     echo $sum_item; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this.

```
$sum_item=0;
foreach($requests as $request):
     if($request->is_approved == 2) { 
         $sum_item++; 
     }
endforeach;

echo $sum_item;
```